# Converting NSStrings to Json

Tags: objective-c

I have search a lot ,i did found many answers, but not the specific one i need-which is so simple.

I want to take 2 **different** `NSString` that the user type, and create a json from them to send to server .

I wrote  this :

```
-(id)stringToJason:(NSString*)stringData 
{
    NSData *data = [stringData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    return json;
}
```

But there is something i dont get. this return 1 nsstring as json.

How would i take 2 different `NSStrings`, and create from them together ,the json ?
Lets say: `userName:me`  (when each one is comes from text field)

json should look like :

```
"Username": "me",
    "Firstname": "r",
    "Lastname": "k",
```

Comment: Could you post an example of how you'd like the resulting JSON to look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're wanting to produce JSON that looks like:

```
{
   "Username":"me",
   "Firstname":"r",
   "Lastname":"k"
}
```

Where `r` and `k` are values taken from the textfields, you could write a method along the lines of this:

```
-(NSData*)jsonFromFirstName:(NSString*)firstName andLastName:(NSString*)lastName
{
    NSDictionary* dic = @{@"Username" : @"me", @"Firstname" : firstName, @"Lastname" : lastName};
    // In production code, _check_for_errors!
    NSData* json = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dic options:0 error:nil];
    return json;
}
```

You would call this method, passing the `r` (`firstName`) and `k` (`lastName`) values to it. It would construct a dictionary that has the structure of the desired JSON, with the desired values. You'd then use `NSJSONSerialization`'s `-dataWithJSONObject:options:error` selector to convert the dictionary into a JSON data object (stored in an NSData object). You then have the data to send to the server!

The dictionary created in the first line of the method could be expanded as much as you desired, and you could even pass in non-strings (such as numbers, arrays, or even other dictionaries!).

Comment: thanks a lot. this is clear now. but i was thinking how would i make something general that i can send it each time a different number of arguments ?

Comment: should i use array of nsstrings and send it to the function ?

Comment: @user1994291 It depends on how you want the resulting JSON to look. You could pass it an `NSArray` of `NSStrings`, and then include that array directly in the dictionary (such as: `@{@"Aliases" : arrayOfAliases}`). I'd suggest playing around with passing various data structures to `-dataWithJSONObject:options:error` and `NSLog`ging the resulting stringified data, to see how things come out.

Comment: thanks a lot . thats what i do (but i dont know how to run a for loop on the dictionary so i can add it every iteration a new index from the array -the goal is that the function can get a unknown number of nsstrings and can fit to many projects.. )

Comment: @user1994291 If you have an array of strings, you could just plonk that right in, or even pass that to `-dataWithJSONObject:options:error` directly. Converting to/from JSON takes few enough lines that you'd likely be better off not writing a super-generic function to call NSJSONSerialization's methods, but just call them when you need to directly.